# Oracle SQL - creating a loop (oracle11g)

Tags: sql, oracle

Please can you explain how I could create a loop function to give me the same result as the following,

```
select  to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 0),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 0),'YYYY') today,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 1),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 1),'YYYY') date_1,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 2),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 2),'YYYY') date_2,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 3),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 3),'YYYY') date_3,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 4),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 4),'YYYY') date_4,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 5),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 5),'YYYY') date_5,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 6),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 6),'YYYY') date_6,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 7),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 7),'YYYY') date_7,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 8),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 8),'YYYY') date_6,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 9),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- 9),'YYYY') date_9,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-10),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-10),'YYYY') date_10,
        to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-11),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-11),'YYYY') date_11
from dual
```

I want the results to populate in to columns, like ...

[image]

I want to use this go back to Jan 2000 but, don't really want to repeat these lines. Also, every month I would have to add another line to cover the new month. I am wondering if there is a LOOP function in SQL similar to a DO ... LOOP UNTIL in Excel.

Thanks

SMORF

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?  What do you mean by "loop function"?

Comment: Hi, I want to use this go back to Jan 2000 but, don't really want to repeat these lines. Also, every month I would have to add another line to cover the new month. I am wondering if there is a LOOP function in SQL similar to a DO ... LOOP UNTIL in Excel

Comment: `SQL` and `PL/SQL` are diffeent engines. If you can achieve something in `SQL`, there is no reason to do it in `PL/SQL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
select * from (
select level-1 as num, 
to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- (level-1)),'MM')||'-'||to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),- (level-1)),'YYYY') as dte
from dual
connect by level <= 12
)
pivot  (
max(dte) as "DATE"
for num in (0 as "CURRENT", 1 as "1", 2 as "2", 3 as "3", 4 as "4", 5 as "5",6 as "6",7 as "7",8 as "8",9 as "9",10 as "10", 11 as "11"))
```

Output:

```
CURRENT_DATE    1_DATE  2_DATE  3_DATE  4_DATE  5_DATE  6_DATE  7_DATE  8_DATE  9_DATE  10_DATE 11_DATE
10-2014 09-2014 08-2014 07-2014 06-2014 05-2014 04-2014 03-2014 02-2014 01-2014 12-2013 11-2013
```

Comment: Thanks tbone, this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  You could do what you want if you had a separate row for each month.  I would write this as something like this:

```
with n as (
      select level - 1 as n
      from dual
      connect by level <= months_between(sysdate, date '2000-01-01')
select to_char(add_months(sysdate, n.n), 'YYYY-MM')
from n;
```

(Note:  I changed the format from MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM because I much prefer the latter, but you can keep MM-YYYY if you like.)

Making these columns is a problem for SQL.  A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  To have a variable number, you will need to use dynamic SQL.  I would suggest that you google "Oracle dynamic pivot" to get some ideas on how to solve this.